# What does "to handle fruit" mean?

Tags: meaning, definition, word-meaning

From the movie *Union Depot (1932)*

A woman tries to pick some fruits at a stand, but she buys nothing saying

> I should think you might handle fresh fruit once in a while.

The store clerk replies

> I'm too busy... I leave the handling to my customers.

You can see the video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2qg5I97BXgQ). The dialogue starts at [1:57](https://youtu.be/2qg5I97BXgQ?t=1m56s).

What exactly does "to handle fruit/handling fruit" mean?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm guessing  it's supposed to be a play on words. I think the first one means

> [handle](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/handle)
>   14. to deal or trade in:
>   to handle dry goods.
>   (Dictionary.com)

Roughly, she's saying that she expects him to carry fresh fruit occasionally, implying that the current fruits are not fresh.

The second *handle* roughly means *touch*.   By saying that he leaves the handling to the customers, he doesn't mean that the customers stock or manage the fruits. He means that he leaves the *touching* to the customers, implying that his fruits are in fact fresh.

Comment: +1 - the second half ( _I leave the handling to the customers_ ) is a bit of a dig at a customer who paws over all the fruit, searching for the best one, and possibly damaging some of the others in the process.  I haven't watched the video, but I would imagine that she takes slight offense at his statement.